# How to take image ID from navigationview header? (Kotlin, Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, header, android-navigationview

I only started learn Kotlin, and maybe for advanced developers this be some easy. I have header on navigationview, this header have image, image have id. I want when I click on this image, open new activity, but for this, I need take this image id and add onClickListener. How I can take this image id from navigationview header?
Sorry for mistakes, English is not my first language.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwdvF.png)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var adapter: MyAdapter? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        binding.navView.getHeaderView()



        binding.navView.header
        var list = ArrayList<ListItem>()

        list.addAll(fillArrays(getImageId(R.array.imAvatar),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvName),resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvPosition),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvNumber),getImageId(R.array.imFlag),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo),getImageId(R.array.imInfo),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo2),getImageId(R.array.imInfo2),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo3),getImageId(R.array.imInfo3),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo4),getImageId(R.array.imInfo4),
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo5),getImageId(R.array.imInfo5)))


        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rcView).hasFixedSize()
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rcView).layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = MyAdapter(list, this)
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rcView).adapter = adapter


    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.id_result -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "3-3 (6-5)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityResult::class.java))


            }
            R.id.id_liverpool -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gerrard",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                adapter?.updateAdapter(fillArrays(getImageId(R.array.imAvatar),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvName),resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvPosition),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvNumber),getImageId(R.array.imFlag),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo),getImageId(R.array.imInfo),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo2),getImageId(R.array.imInfo2),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo3),getImageId(R.array.imInfo3),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo4),getImageId(R.array.imInfo4),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo5),getImageId(R.array.imInfo5)))
            }
            R.id.id_milan -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Maldini",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                adapter?.updateAdapter(fillArrays(getImageId(R.array.imAvatarM),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvNameM),resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvPositionM),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvNumberM),getImageId(R.array.imFlagM),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfoM),getImageId(R.array.imInfoM),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo2M),getImageId(R.array.imInfo2M),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo3M),getImageId(R.array.imInfo3M),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo4M),getImageId(R.array.imInfo4M),
                    resources.getStringArray(R.array.tvInfo5M),getImageId(R.array.imInfo5M)))

            }
        }
        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    fun fillArrays(imAvatar:IntArray,tvName:Array<String>,tvPosition:Array<String>,tvNumber:Array<String>,imFlag:IntArray,tvInfo:Array<String>,imInfo:IntArray,tvInfo2:Array<String>,imInfo2:IntArray,tvInfo3:Array<String>,imInfo3:IntArray,tvInfo4:Array<String>,imInfo4:IntArray,tvInfo5:Array<String>,imInfo5:IntArray):List<ListItem>
    {
        var listItemArray = ArrayList<ListItem>()
        for(n in 0..tvName.size -1)
        {
            var listItem = ListItem(imAvatar[n],tvName[n],tvPosition[n],tvNumber[n],imFlag[n],tvInfo[n], imInfo[n],tvInfo2[n], imInfo2[n],tvInfo3[n], imInfo3[n],tvInfo4[n], imInfo4[n],tvInfo5[n], imInfo5[n])
            listItemArray.add(listItem)
        }
        return listItemArray
    }


    fun getImageId(imageArrayId:Int):IntArray
    {
        var tArray:TypedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(imageArrayId)
        val count = tArray.length()
        val ids = IntArray(count)
        for (i in ids.indices)
        {
            ids[i] = tArray.getResourceId(i, 0)
        }
        tArray.recycle()
        return ids
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/header_main_height"
android:background="@color/liverpool_red">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imHeader"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/champions_league_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imHeader"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imHeader"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imHeader" />
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Like your layout file, and your kotlin code.

Comment: I don't know how to do this correct( Site tell me, that my post tool long when I try to add code, and how to add screenshot I don't know( But code not have something about header, only for navigationview, and layout have simple layout and id's.

Comment: Yes, it is encouraged not to simply post all your code here. You should post a minimal reproducible example. For example, Is this *I have header on navigationview, this header have image, image have id.* done through .xml layout? If yes, you can post that xml file showing your navigation view, header and image.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do this correct? I need to edit my question for it?

Comment: Yes, you should edit your question for extra information.

Comment: I don't know how it help, but I'm done)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first take headerView then find your image id and set click listener of that.

```
var headerView = binding.headerView

var imageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.image_id)

imageView.setOnClickListerner(object: {

          }
        );
```

Comment: I found something like that in google, but not understand, because noob in Kotlin and use binding. Can you tell me how use this with binding?